# How to set a max retry value in App Engine Task Queue?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

I have the following retry parameters:

```
<retry-parameters>
    <task-retry-limit>7</task-retry-limit>
    <task-age-limit>1d</task-age-limit>
    <min-backoff-seconds>1</min-backoff-seconds>
    <max-backoff-seconds>30</max-backoff-seconds>
</retry-parameters>
```

But when I check the queue, I see retries like `45`. I had set the `task-retry-limit` to 7. So why is it going beyond that? How to set a max retry value? I am using App Engine standard with push based task queue and Java 8 env. Thanks.

---

```
private Queue fsQueue = QueueFactory.getQueue(FS_QUEUE_NAME);
// ...

Product fp = new Product();
fp.setId("someid");
// ...
TaskOptions opts = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/api/task/fs/product").method(TaskOptions.Method.POST)
                .payload(utils.toJSONBytes(fp), "application/json");
fsQueue.add(opts);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your issue is related to the fact of using the `queue.xml` being [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/queueref). You should be using the [`queue.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/queueref-yaml) instead.

You should also bear in mind that if you are using the [Cloud Tasks API](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) to manage your queue as well this might cause some collisions. In [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/queue-yaml) you'll find information on how to handle the most common problems.

Comment: I am not using Cloud Tasks API. I am using `com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TaskOptions` to push to the queue. If I specify yaml, then deployment fails because it couldn't find these files. Same for appengine-web config. So I am using xml files.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with a minimum reproducible code so I can help you further?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the snippet. I think that you should use the Class [RetryOptions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/RetryOptions#class-retryoptions), and push those options to your queue as you are already doing with the TaskOptions.